# System.Text.Json how to deserialize

Tags: .net, system.text.json

I have implemented a EANCode13 class with a constructor with a parameter like this:

```
public class EAN13Code {
  public EAN13Code(string value) {
      // validate it 
  }

  [JsonConstructor]
  public EAN13Code(long value) {
     // validate it
  }
}
```

```
public class ApiResponse
{
    public EAN13Code Code { get; }

    [JsonConstructor]
    public ApiResponse(EAN13Code code) {
       Code = code;
    }
}
```

and a JSON like this:

```
{
   "code" : 978020137962
}
```

Trying to deserialize simply like this doesn't work:

```
var reponse = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ApiResponse>(json);
```

What do I need to do make it work?

Do I need a custom Json Converter? Writing one is easy but isn't there a simpler or better way?

Is there a library which can help?

Comment: There's no `implicit` operator in your code.  But even if there were I don't believe `System.Text.Json` would pick up on it, so you will need to write a custom `JsonConverter<EAN13Code>`.  The JSON corresponding to `ApiResponse` would look like `{ "code" : { "value" : 978020137962 } }`.

Comment: Thanks. I removed that part from the title. Using an implicit operator was one of the things I tried and didn't work.  So it appears JsonConverter is the only way? Could there be another way to at least not create a JsonConverter for all the objects? Like a common JsonConverter using maybe implicit operators